# ¿Cómo agregar una subconsulta usando JPA Nativequery? solucionar el error ORA-01427

Tags: java, sql, jpa, microservices

Tengo las siguientes tablas **CONTROL** y **ESTADO**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name= "CONTROL")
    public class ControlEntity{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "CLAVE_ESTADO")
    private claveEstado; 
    
    @Column(name = "COMENTARIO")
    private comentario; 
    
    @Column(name = "HORA_INICIAL")
    private Date horaInicial;
    
    }


    @Entity
    @Table(name= "ESTADO")
    public class EstadoEntity{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CLAVE_ESTADO")
    private claveEstado; 
    
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPCION")
    private descripcionEstado; 
    
    
    }
```

y el siguiente es el Query que muestra el listado de la tabla CONTROL y lo hace bien

```
@Query(value = "SELECT C.ID, C.CLAVE_ESTADO, C.COMENTARIO, C.HORA_INICIAL FROM CONTROL C", 
        nativeQuery = true)
List<ControlEntity> consulta();
```

En el campo  **C.CLAVE_ESTADO**  muestra solo la clave, por ejemplo pinta la clave PAG, para la descripción PAGADO o la clave PEND, para la descripcion PENDIENTE,
lo que quiero es que muestre como tal la **descripcion** y no la clave, y eso esta en la tabla **ESTADO** , por lo cual agregue una subconsulta de la tabla ESTADO

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT C.ID,(SELECT EST.DESCRIPCION FROM CONTROL CON, ESTADO EST
    WHERE CON.CLAVE_ESTADO = EST.CLAVE_ESTADO), C.COMENTARIO, C.HORA_INICIAL FROM CONTROL C", 
    nativeQuery = true)
    List<ControlEntity> consulta();
```

pero manda el error

> 2023-04-18 14:46:41.258  WARN 2028 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1427, SQLState:
> 21000
> 2023-04-18 14:46:41.258 ERROR 2028 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-01427: la subconsulta
> de una sola fila devuelve más de una fila

como puedo solucionar esto?
que necesito para mostrar en mi query la descripcion que requiero de la otra tabla?

Answer (score 2):

Podrías intentar probar consiguiendo acceso la descripción a través de un inner join, algo como esto podría funcionar aunque no lo puedo asegurar sin conocer como las tablas están relacionadas.

```
   @Query(value = "SELECT C.ID, EST.DESCRIPCION, C.COMENTARIO, C.HORA_INICIAL FROM CONTROL C
 INNER JOIN ESTADO EST ON C.CLAVE_ESTADO = EST.CLAVE_ESTADO", 
    nativeQuery = true)
    List<ControlEntity> consulta();
```

Teniendo acceso directo a la base de datos puedes probar con

```
SELECT C.ID, EST.DESCRIPCION, C.COMENTARIO, C.HORA_INICIAL FROM CONTROL C
     INNER JOIN ESTADO EST ON C.CLAVE_ESTADO = EST.CLAVE_ESTADO
```

Comment: gracias, si me funcionó asi, solo que al mostrar los datos , los muestra en desorden, no como estan en la bd, asi consecutivos los registros 1,2,3,...

Comment: podrías agregar un ORDER BY 'COLUMNA QUE NECESITAS EN ORDEN' al final de la query y así organizas la información ASC o DESC según lo necesites

Answer (score 1):

El subquery donde tienes `(SELECT EST.DESCRIPCION FROM CONTROL CON, ESTADO EST  WHERE CON.CLAVE_ESTADO = EST.CLAVE_ESTADO)` está devolviendo más de un registro; te sugiero agregar al subquery en el where lo siguiente `AND C.ID=CON.ID`. Quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
(SELECT EST.DESCRIPCION FROM CONTROL CON, ESTADO EST  WHERE CON.CLAVE_ESTADO = EST.CLAVE_ESTADO AND C.ID=CON.ID)
```

> Lo anterior dependiendo la cantidad de filas en las Tablas en uso puede generar se consuma bastante tiempo en devolver resultado.

Otra opción que considero la más prudente es que tu Query quede de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT 
   C.ID, C.CLAVE_ESTADO, EST.DESCRIPCION AS DESCRIPCION_ESTADO,
   C.COMENTARIO, C.HORA_INICIAL 
FROM 
   CONTROL C
LEFT JOIN ESTADO EST ON EST.CLAVE_ESTADO = C.CLAVE_ESTADO
```